# could not update a variable in an angular service with ajax response data and use is to filter

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

i'm using the same code from [this article](http://blog.trifork.com/2014/04/10/internationalization-with-angularjs/) (internationalization with angularjs)
...
but i need the "tables" variable to be fetched from an ajax request response using "$http get" but couldn't !! ... here is the code,

```
var xlat = angular.module('xlat', []);

xlat.factory('xlatService', function ($http) {
    var currentLanguage = 'en';
    // var tables = $.extend(true, {}, initialXlatTables);
    var tables = {
        'en': {
            'textKeys.events': 'Events'
        }
    };

    var service = {
        getData: function () {
            var req = {
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'local/en_US.php',
                cache: true,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'json'
                }
            };

            $http(req).success(function (data) {
                tables = data;
            });
        },
        setCurrentLanguage: function (newCurrentLanguage) {
            currentLanguage = newCurrentLanguage;
        },
        getCurrentLanguage: function () {
            return currentLanguage;
        },
        xlat: function (label, parameters) {
            service.getData();     
            if (parameters === null || $.isEmptyObject(parameters)) {
                return tables[currentLanguage][label];
            } else {
                return $interpolate(tables[currentLanguage][label])(parameters);
            }
        }
    };

    return service;
});
```

but the variable "tables" does not change when i use the filter...

```
var xlat = angular.module('xlat', []);    
xlat.filter('xlat', ['xlatService', function (xlatService) {         
            return function (label, parameters) {
                return xlatService.xlat(label, parameters);
            };
        }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
var xlat = angular.module('xlat', []);    
xlat.filter('xlat', ['xlatService', function (xlatService) {         
    function myfiler(label, parameters) {
        return xlatService.xlat(label, parameters);
    };
    myfiler.$stateful = true;
    return myfilter;
}]);
```

Stateful filters - 
https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/docs/guide/filter

Secod: you should load tables in factory method not in xlat function.

Comment: thanks you,
i will check the stateful later today,
but about loading the tables in the factory method, i tried to do so but did not get any result .. the filter was always called first and then the load

Comment: it worked .. "service.getData();" is called before the "return service"

Comment: But it doesn't matter if it's called before or after. What matters is if it will end before. But even this doesn't matter if you create stateful filter as it will be reevaluated during digest cycle. That's why you should use $stateful very carefully as can harm performance.